# Matlab save iterated vectors in loop

Tags: matlab, vector, while-loop, save, mat

I am trying to save vectors `1x100` which are changing in every loop.
code sample:

```
i=1;
while i
   for i=1:N
      A(i)   = A(i) + B(i)*i;
   end
   for i=1:N
      C(i)=D(i) + B(i)*dt;
   end
   t=t+dt;
   if t<=tmax;
      save 'savedata.mat', C, A`
      i=i+1
   else
      break
   end
end
```

I tried the above code without success.

Please, any idea is more than welcome.

Comment: I see that you are missing `end` at the end of the code.

Comment: this is a sample code. My original code is huge! My questions is not about the saving data. Please, can you help me on this ?

Comment: you need to explain the code better. What are you trying to do in these loops? What do you mean by "without success"? I think you are saving the data on the same file over and over. Is it intended behavior?

Comment: Yes, you have right. In the end of the program, I see only the last iteration data on file. As it is the file over written on each loop. I need to save All the loops data. The A and C  vectors depended by the time. So, on each loop have other values. Eventually what I want to do is to have a Amatrix and Cmatrix, which in each raw or column to have each time iteration result.

Comment: Using `i` in the definition of every loop is probably not the best idea, I'm sure it could lead to some strange behaviour.

Comment: I have another version:
while<=tmax , and at the end t=t+dt 
So, if it is like that, any idea for saving the data?

Comment: @user1640255 So what is the problem in saving `A,B,C and D` after both the while loops get over? You can do something like: `save(['data_loop' num2str(i) '.mat'],'A','B','C','D')`. Also, please clear the variables `A,B,C and D` just after `while`. Its a good practice to avoid over-writing and minimizing errors in your code. Don't use `i` in both the loops.

Answer (score 0):

For a better answer you should provide some more details of your problem.

Supposed `tmax, dt, N, A, B, D` are given and t starts at 0:

```
% preallocate finalA and finalC:
num_steps = length(0:dt:tmax);
finalA = zeros(num_steps,N);
finalC = zeros(num_steps,N);
% loop:
for j = 1:num_steps
   for i=1:N
      finalA(j,i) = A(i) + B(i)*i;
      finalC(j,i) = D(i) + B(i)*dt;
   end
end
save('savedata.mat', 'finalA', 'finalC');
```